# Global variable & local variable in kendo

Tags: jquery, arrays, kendo-ui, global-variables, kendo-grid

I am working on a kendo grid.

I have declared some variables as global and I need to change the value inside some function. And the result should reflect on global variable.

```
var array1= [1,2,3]

 $("#cancelChanges").kendoButton({
                    click: function (options) {
    enter code here
                    array1.pop()
                    }
                })
```

after the change if I use the array on some other function the result should be array1=[1,2]

I have a index array declared as global variable. If I select any checkbox the array will update with the index of the selected row. There is one cancel button, If I click the button then the array should remove all the selected values. And if I again select any new row then the array should append with the selected row index.

Currently If I  click the cancel button and select any other checkbox, the array is containing both (currently selected & and selected before clicking cancel button) index values.

How can I delete data from an array which is declared as global variable inside a local function and reflect the changes in global variable?

Comment: a) what makes you think it's not working and b) you've not described a problem that can be answered.  Have a read of [ask].

Comment: Question updated

Comment: As long as you don't create a *second* variable (ie with the same name) then you will be using the local variable, as in the example you've provided.  You might like to provide more code so we can see what you're doing / doing wrong.   See [mcve].